# How do I select text between two specific symbols in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm very new to Perl. I'm currently going through this Perl file and I've got this variable where I was able to format it down to get all the text after the "<" symbol using this line I found from another stackflow question.

```
($tempVariable) = $Line =~ /(\<.*)\s*$/;
```

So currently whenever I print this variable, I get the output

```
$tempVariable = <some text here      @typeOf and more text here after
```

I need to get everything between the "<" symbol and the "@"symbol.

I tried looking at other stackflow questions and tried implementing it to mines but I keep getting errors so if anybody could help me out I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my ($substr) = $str =~ /<([^<\@]*)\@/
   or die "No match";
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a regex that

- looks for the starting `<` character
- then (your question is unclear on this point)

  - captures one-or-more non-`@` characters, or
  - captures zero-or-more non-`@` characters
- looks for the trailing `@` character
- also not specified in your question: do you need to strip leading and trailing white space from the match?

I.e.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $Line = '<some text here      @typeOf and more text here after';
my $tempVariable;

# alternative 1: one-or-more characters
($tempVariable) = $Line =~ /<([^@]+)@/
   or die "No match alternative 1";
print "Alternative 1: '${tempVariable}'\n";

# alternative 2: zero-or-more characters
($tempVariable) = $Line =~ /<([^@]*)@/
   or die "No match alternative 2";
print "Alternative 2: '${tempVariable}'\n";

exit 0;
```

Test run (white space is not stripped):

```
$ perl dummy.pl
Alternative 1: 'some text here      '
Alternative 2: 'some text here      '
```